# There were no valid user or no valid group when I try to mount NTFS partition with ntfs-3g usermap

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I want to mount a NTFS external drive that must have read and write access for my user profile. So following the NTFS-3G guide, to generate the mapping file, I have tried this:

```
sudo ntfsusermap /dev/sda1
```

when I launch this command, it asks me to input the user UID, so I input 1000 that is my account UID and I get the message:

> You have defined no group, this can cause problems Do you accept
> defining a standard group ?

(I suspect this is the cause of the issue but it hasn't asked me to indicate the GID, so I don't know how it's supposed to set it correctly in the mapping file creation procedure)

The generated mapping file has following structure

```
# Generated by ntfsusermap for Linux, v 1.2.0
:p1:S-1-5-21-7728005000-258165423-2201256221-513
p1:p1:S-1-5-21-7728005000-258165423-2201256221-1001
```

And last line `S-1-5-21-7728005000-258165423-2201256221-1001`match exactly the SID of the Windows user account used to write the files already present on the external hard drive I want to map.

then I move the mapping file in .NTFS-3G folder inside the disk and edit fstab adding the line

```
UUID=<MYDISKUID> /home/<mymountpoint> ntfs-3g defaults,dmode=770,fmode=660 0 0
```

now, if I try to mount the drive, I get the error:

> There were no valid user or no valid group

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the group `p1` does not exist on your system. The first warning message tells you that your user has no group, so it writes a group with the same name as your user into the mapping file, even if it does not exist.

You have to create a group called `p1` and add your user to it.

I had the same problem after switching to a different distro that did not define a group for my user. Adding the group fixed the permissions and the "There were no valid user or no valid group" warning.